# How can I tell if someone is a friend of mine in Facebook Graph API V2.0 and above?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, facebook-friends

In my App, I go through different groups and pages, and check public posts that were posted by people that haven't installed my App.
How can I tell if a person that posted something is a friend of mine or not?

I am well aware that \me\friends returns only the list of friends who also installed my app, I don't want to get the full list, only check a specific person. 
I am also well aware that Facebook currently returns app-scoped Facebook ID of a user of enters my application, but also returns public data about people using their non-app-scoped FB ID - however without this simple piece of info.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible until both persons have given your app the `user_friends` permission.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends#readperms
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends#readmodifiers

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The other user needs to login to your app and approve user_friends permission to your app. Otherwise it means they they have not approved it and you will not get the information